# To use random.choice() to get random key and random word from assigned list to key

Tags: python-3.x

I've a dictionary with assigned lists to the keys. What I'm struggling with is to get random key: animals or fruits and then random item from list that is assigned to the key. For example: animal and then either koala or kangaroo and knowing what was choose, animal or fruit?

```
animal = ['koala', 'kangaroo']
fruit = ['banana', 'apple']
kind = {'animals': animal, 'fruits': fruit}
```

I've done it in that way:

```
import random
animal = ['koala', 'kangaroo']
fruit = ['banana', 'apple']
kinds = [animal,fruit]

    kind = random.choice(kinds)
    print(kind)
    word = random.choice(kind)
    print(word)
```

I get a random item from fruits or animal but **print(kind)** doesn't prints what it is **animal** or **fruit** but the list: ['kolala', 'kangaroo']

Comment: You started by saying you have a dictionary but there is no dictionary here. If you actually saved it as a dict you will get what you want `d = {'animal': ['koala', 'kangaroo'], 'fruit': ['banana', 'apple']}` and then `kind = choice(d)` and `word = choice(d[kind])`

Comment: No @Tomerikoo, it is a dictionary with arrays as key values.

Comment: oh sorry, i only read the first piece of code :|

Comment: @frederic there is no dictionary in the question. Just lists...

Comment: Yes @Tomerikoo, in the second code piece there are only lists, but as i wrote already, i only read the first piece of code, and there IS a dict there !

Comment: @frederic and I actually missed the first piece :) if OP used that in the second code there would be no problem

Comment: wow what a messing - er, missing ! - about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted something like this:

```
animal = ['koala', 'kangaroo']
fruit = ['banana', 'apple']
kinds = {'animals': animal, 'fruits': fruit}

import random
kind = random.choice(list(kinds.keys()))
print(kind)  # --> fruits
word = random.choice(kinds[kind])
print(word)  # --> apple
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kinds = {'animals': animal, 'fruits': fruit}

kind = random.choice(list(kinds.keys()))

word = random.choice(kinds[kind])

print(word)
```